# Can you do an ajax request in handlebars.js helpers or partial?

Tags: handlebars.js

Can you do an ajax request in handlebars registerHelper or in an registerPartial?

i want to populate some select dropdownboxes in my handlebartemplate but i want to populate them with data from an remote json 
is that possible or is it an other way to populate dropdown widt standard values that comes from server

Answer (score 0):

The registerPartial is something that calls another template so I would say no this is not designed to call a javascript function. But in helpers you call a javascript function so you can place any code you want into your helper and then return the values you want.

I had the same needs but I wanted to call a subtemplate and an ajax different result so I've opted for something that calls recursively new templates (not partials) inside the evaluated current template. I just do a loop after evaluating my current template and launching new templates based on some css classes.